# My terminal keeps closing. What's going on?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Issue Type: Bug

Whenever I open the VSCode Terminal, it stays open for about 20-30 seconds, and then closes automatically. Always. By itself, automatically.

"The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" was terminated with exit code: 4294967295."

VS Code version: Code 1.67.1 (da15b6f, 2022-05-06T12:37:03.389Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000
Restricted Mode: No

I've tried this on GitHub.
(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149846)

At first, the issue was fixed. But rn is not working anymore.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please how did you resolve this issue

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue on my `Visual Studio Code` as well and solved it by reading this Github issue opened on it's project:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62041

Check in VSCode settings that the shell you are using (If it's OSX) is set to `/bin/sh`:

[image]

Comment: This workaround changes the shell instead of really fixing the issue :(

Answer (score 2):

I had simular issue. Solve it by just rebooting VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the same problem here the whole day, I fixed it by running this command on my VS Code terminal:

- First press F1 on your VS Code
- type **Terminal: Select Default Profile**
- then select **Command Prompt**.

it worked normally afterward for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching my default terminal to Powershell.  I suspect that you can also use c:\windows\sysWow64\cmd.exe to access the 64bit terminal shell.  I suspect that VSCode has issues with 32/64 bit differences.